# Function to get current timestamp in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code to get the current timestamp so that I can save it as a part of the key in leveldb database.

```
export default function timestamp() {
  var [seconds, nanoseconds] = process.hrtime()
  return seconds * 1000000000 + nanoseconds
}
```

I am wondering are there any downsides to use this function. Or are there any better alternatives to get current timestamp in node.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work - `process.hrtime()` does not return with a timestamp of any useful form unless you compare it to another `process.hrtime()` in the same running program (typically used for measuring performance).

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time):

> These times are relative to an arbitrary time in the past, and not
>   related to the time of day and therefore not subject to clock drift.
>   The primary use is for measuring performance between intervals

Bottom line is that the `arbitrary time in the past` could be anything, and not the same "epoch" as `new Date()`.

There is no way in native JavaScript or Node (without making OS system calls through libraries, etc.) that I know of to get a more granular resolution than the millisecond times from Date.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one:)

```
+new Date()
```

Comment: This is what I use (well, I use `timestamp = Date.now()`) but based on OPs code they are looking for nanoseconds. Date.now() only gives you millisecond precision. While that's good enough for me to use as a DB key, for very fast transactions it might not work.